# How to use SQL TOP command in jasper report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

How to get only first 5 records in iReport?

SQL query:

```
select top 5 * 
from [order]
```

This static query is working but this query with parameter in ireport doesn't work:

```
select top $P{NoOfRecords} * 
from [order]
```

Comment: Check the type of $P{NoOfRecords}

Comment: its java.lang.Integer type

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Sometime i got result sometime i got this execption.. error net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jrexception unable to get next record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got solution
 Take Report_Count variable 
and just set filter expression $V{REPORT_COUNT}<=$P{NoOfRecords}

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply pass a value to the built-in parameter called [REPORT_MAX_COUNT](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#REPORT_MAX_COUNT).